# Adding custom CSS to third party plugin in wordpress through javascript from functions.php

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I am trying to hide/show button through CSS for logged-in and not logged-in users. I can do it for the buttons in the theme through Javascript DOM properties. But here the buttons are of  a third party plugin and I am trying to achieve it the same way as I would do for a theme button but I am not able to. Here is my code

```
add_action('wp_head', 'stylebutton', 1, 1);
function stylebutton() {
     if (!is_user_logged_in()) { 
     ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var div = document.getElementsByClassName("bw-widget__cta");
    div[0].style.display = "none";
    });
    </script>
<?php   
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: Instead of using JavaScript, why aren't you instead using CSS to hide the button? This can also be done depending on `is_user_logged_in()`. The thing is: the button of the third party plugin may only exist after the `load` event, if the button is created either through the plugin's JS, or after an AJAX call. Therefore, it might not exist yet when your script triggers. Thus, use CSS add `display: none;` to a selector matching the `.bw-widget__cta`.

Comment: thank you for the solution...but can you please write its code for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CSS to hide the element works like so:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'stylebutton');
function stylebutton() {
  if (!is_user_logged_in()) { 
  ?>
  <style type="text/css">
    .bw-widget__cta {
      display: none !important;
    }
  </style>
  <?php   
  }
}
?>
```

Be careful, though. Since I do not know how the third party plugin's CSS looks like, I added an `!important` to force-override it. If this doesn't work by any chance, you might have to use the developer tools of your browser to inspect the button element and see which CSS rule has precedence.

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work...and I also inspect the developer tools, there aren't any precedence problem...It is just that it is not selecting that class

Comment: Did you check if the CSS-code above is added to the page (if you're viewing the page not being logged in)? I assumed `.bw-widget__cta` is the button's class name - since you were trying to hide this via JS. Maybe the CSS selector is still off. But first make sure the code is actually adding the above CSS code. Next, use the inspector to construct a valid CSS selector.

Comment: Thank you Damocles. Actually I was targeting the wrong CSS selector. Your solution worked.